# Covariance of dependent, conditionally independent, variables

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I'm trying to find the covariance between two variables that are dependent, but conditionally independent.  My two random variables, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.d. and their probability density functions are $f(x_i)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^-\frac{(x_i-M)^2}{2\sigma^2}$.  But M is a random variable itself.  How do I calculate $Cov(X_i,X_j)$?

Eventually, I'll want to mess around with the probability density function of M, but it can be either discrete or continuous. If it helps to answer, two simple cases could be (1) $f(M=\mu)=\frac{1}{c_2-c_1}$ on $(c_1,c_2)$ or (2) $P(M=c_1)=0.6$ and $P(M=c_2)=0.4$.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Just a note: $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not i.i.d. (independent and identically distributed) since this would imply that they are independent. They are just i.d.

Comment: Whoops.  I'm used to writing iid so I didn't even notice I did that.  Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $X_1=M+\sigma Y_1$ and $X_2=M+\sigma Y_2$ where $(Y_1,Y_2)$ is i.i.d. standard normal and independent of $M$, hence $E[X_i]=E[M]$, $X_1X_2=M^2+\sigma M(Y_1+Y_2)+\sigma^2Y_1Y_2$ and $E[X_1X_2]=E[M^2]$, in particular $\mathrm{Cov}(X_1,X_2)=\mathrm{var}(M)$.

Comment: Thanks.  That's definitely right, but it doesn't help me with my actual problem.  I was trying to simplify it a bit, so that it would be easier to answer, but I don't think I can apply your advice to my real problem.  

I'm new to this site.  Should I edit my question, or write a new one?

Comment: Once you received an answer, it is improper to modify substantially your question, hence I would say: ask a new one (but this time, think harder about what you really want to ask...).